# OSX VPN IP address conflict locally and on server?

Tags: osx-lion, vpn, osx-server

I am trying to learn about VPN using OSX and have a question I cannot find the answer to. Any help will be appreciated.

I have an office machine running OSX server 10.7. I set up VPN on it today and set up my laptop (running OSX 10.8) to access it. I am able to connect, but have a problem accessing a machine by its IP address on the office network. I suspect I have and issue because both my networks use the block 10.0.1.xx. Before I change one of my networks IP range I wanted to ask if this is the actual problem or if there is an easier way to resolve this. How would my laptop know that 10.0.1.127 is on the office network and it needs to look over the VPN connection?

Thanks for any help. Trying to wrap my brain around this whole VPN thing.

Thom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, having both address blocks set to the same address space is very confusing for your workstation. The actual problem is more gateway related, as your machine now has two gateways with (likely) the same IP address.

There is no good way to get that to work using the same IP range on both the local and remote networks.

Note that I said "Good way" I'm certain it's possible, just more trouble than it's worth.